# C# Split with contains

Tags: c#

I have a few trouble with my project.

My string is

```
11713,Julia's_Candy,Julia's Candy
1713,Julia's_Head,Julia's Head
```

Now I am using my code like this `string line;`

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"db.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(("1713"+",")))
        {
            label1.Text = line.Split(',')[2];
        }
    }
}
```

I want `Julia's Head` to be print out but it have the same number that including in `11713,Julia's_Candy,Julia's Candy`.And its print `Julia's Candy`

So I want to ask that how can I fix this code for more accurate.

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at `line.StartsWith("1713,")`?

Comment: Split first, and check the index 0, that will give you the real number

Comment: @RufusL Sorry My question is a abit wrong , What I mean is more accurate.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you please better explain?

Comment: What does it mean by _but it have the same number that including in 11713,Julia's_Candy,Julia's Candy_?

Comment: I didn't understand what you expect.

Comment: Google "c# parse csv file" to learn how to avoid stringly typing.

Comment: @RufusL its work now. Thank you . You can add the answer so i will accept the answer.

Comment: Are you saying that using `StartsWith` does not solve the problem?

Comment: @Sach In my string it have 11713 and 1713. And I use Contain to check. So the output will give 2 output because all of the two data contain 1713

Comment: @RufusL SOLVED. Can you please answer the question. So I will accept it.

Comment: Why not just do the split first, then you can compare the number?

Comment: @RufusL Yep. That's way is approve to.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the static method `System.IO.File.ReadLines` is a wrapper around `StreamReader` and makes the code much simpler: `foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("db.txt")) { // do something with line here }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split first, you can use the first column as an Id column and search for exact match:

```
string line;
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"db.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var values = line.Split(",");
        if (values[0] == "1713")
        {
            label1.Text = values[2];
        }
    }
}
```